# what actualy new() do with generic method in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, type-constraints

i was refactoring some code and found method that doing some cashe behavior regardless, i found at the end of method `new()` 
my question is what this new do and the most important what are the pros and cons using it

```
public T GetOrDefaultByCode<T>(string key) where T : ILookup, new()
        {
         //some thing to done here
        }
```

I've tried to remove it nothing happens and with it every thing still working fine

Comment: It just means that whatever `T` is must be able to be instantiated, i.e. not abstract.

Answer (score 1):

From [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters):

> where T : new():
>
> The type argument must have a public parameterless constructor. When
> used together with other constraints, the new() constraint must be
> specified last. The new() constraint can't be combined with the struct
> and unmanaged constraints.